# What to do with comments, when a chat room is no longer available?

Tags: discussion

Recently, community touched an yet unsolved question: [Salt analysis using spectroscopy](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/23545/4945).
I wanted to go ahead and clean up the mess in the comments as I hoped it would contain some more information about the original intend of the OP. (I also suspected, that the answer was hidden somewhere there.)
However, the link at the end leading to the chat is a dead end. What happened here? And how to deal with that? All the previous comments are somehow not really leading to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rooms that don't contain enough content are deleted automatically after a while](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention):

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

This specific room only contains 8 chat messages from those two users, which is why it was deleted after it became inactive. This is intentional behaviour, though the interaction with the "move comments to chat" feature is a bit unfortunate here.

I can undelete this specific room, but maybe there should also be changes to the deletion policy for these rooms. Having the links break is problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I thought I read something about that a while ago, but was unsure. I can completely understand the intent behind the whole deleting. I am not too sure if it is worth salvaging the room, since not a lot of people will read through it anyway. The question itself is not that brilliant and might not attract a lot of views anyway.